# Range of ASCII values

Tags: string, code-challenge

#### Your task

Given a string, output the range of ASCII values.

#### Example

Let's say we have the string `Hello`.

We get the ASCII values:

- `H` = 72
- `e` = 101
- `l` = 108
- `l` = 108
- `o` = 111

Now, we get the range (`max - min`):

- 111 - 72 = 39

Our answer is 39.

#### Test cases

```python
Input           Output
Hello, World!   82
aaaaa           0
Code Golf       79
Stack Exchange  88
ASCII           18
```

#### Scoring

For scoring, we will get the range of ASCII/Unicode values of your program source code, and add that to the length of your code in bytes.

For example, with the program `abc`, the score would be:

- 3 (the length of the program) + 2 (the ASCII range of the program) = 5

You can use [this TIO link](https://tio.run/##RYyxCoMwFEX3fMXbTKh16SZ0KJ2Ebu3S8dVEDSR54SUF/XobKeh2OefeG5c8Ubisq/WROENakmC4gkP/0QiuBY@zdArO4G0oQdBhUwvOpiw9Rkmsa0hKieHwcwssSc6F2kLLd5OytqFhg1oqgQUO0irhto0JW4xsQ5bV7XnvOmAMo2mrGnAXDxPGPG3M7exFGR2knvhfPjm1rm/6MvSkDYxkEkyGzQ8) to get your score.

#### Clarifications

- There will be no non-ASCII characters in the input (but your program source code may contain non-ASCII characters)
- There will be no newline characters in the input (but your program source code may include newlines)
- **Lowest score wins**

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25347/114446)

Comment: What if our language uses a different code page e.g. [Jelly's code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page) instead of ASCII/Unicode? I'd suggest using the range of code points + length

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing the Unicode value will still be used in that case. For example, the `£` symbol has a Unicode value of 163, so 163 will be used to calculate the range if there is a `£` in your code.

Comment: What about languages for which the basic coding unit is not a character?  For instance, machine code (basic units = raw bytes) or Nibbles (basic units = raw 4-bit nibbles).  Should we score using the range of values of the basic unit, or the range of values of bytes in the code, or the range of Unicode values if the code was interpreted as if it was a string (but I imagine this might not always be parseable...)?

Comment: Ok.  Is there a site where one can easily convert a series of bytes into a string, to get the Unicode values?  I'm struggling with the byte 154 (hex ```9a```)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen just copy and paste your program source code into the TIO link to get your score. For example, if your program was `£©¶`, the score would be 19+3=22. The basic encoding unit of your program doesn't matter.

Comment: Max minus min is trivial in Dyalog APL (no "golf"), `(⌈/-⌊/)⎕UCS` which is 11 characters (so 11 bytes if classical 1-byte version is used, or 17 bytes in UTF-8).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - don't forget the range of the characters of your code, though: in this case it seems to be a whopping [9069](https://tio.run/##RYw7CsJAFEX7WcXrfIP5FHYBC0kVsIsu4Gl@A/MJM1MkOxAJdm4wG4kThKS7nHPv7UffGX1aFqF6Yz240TELZ5CkHhWBzEDRgJJDDEroEJjZrctACudRUY/GVhE4zlmz@yEDiwaHQEWg4TtxvhI6sTVVyBkF2KDgTK6bWq@xt0J7PFzKvCjAkm7r7BABbeJa69Z3K5MbuxlPEtzT2H/5KPmy4Dy90nie3imfP997Xv4A): not very competitive!

Comment: Looks like they don't optimize for score but shortening then give the score

Comment: It is necessary for the program to be able to handle a string of length 1 (which should always return 0)? Some of the submitted answers cannot handle this.

Comment: @Deadcode yes it is. I'll add comments below the answers that don't support this.

Comment: I assume that 8-bit ASCII-compatible character sets like PETSCII is acceptable for this challenge?

Comment: @ShaunBebbington yeah, that's fine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), score 37 (length 7, range 30)

```
X>GX<ZP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8LOPcImKuD/f3WP1JycfHUA) Or [verify](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8D/Czj3CJirgv0tURch/dY/UnJx8HYXw/KKcFEV1LvVEEADSzvkpqQru@TlpQHZwSWJytoJrRXJGYl56KlDAMdjZ0xNIQ41SBwA) all test cases and source code.

```
X>    % Implicit input. Maximum
G     % Push input again
X<    % Minimum
ZP    % Distance (of code points). Implicit display
```

Answer (score 8):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 79 bytes + 28 = <sup><s>145 138 129 112 111</s></sup> 107

*-7 score thanks to [@Digital Trauma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11259/digital-trauma)

<s>-9</s> -10 score thanks to [@jdt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41374/jdt)*

```c
A,B;D(*C)??<*C<A?A=*C:*C>B?B=*C:0;*++C?D(C):0;??>C(*C)??<A=B=*C;D(C);*C=B-A;??>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVBNT4QwED3TXzGSbAIFshyNXWiga3STve1hDysHLB9LrNAAuhrDXxdbRA/Egz29eTNvOu9xj4u0LscxcmOytTCzKd1gtoloFGB2g1kY01gjn2DHYXRrMVthSkM2D0eB7hPdIJgFsRfp7ljVPXpOq9p6barMRh/IUAzgPu/6UwIBKMLYm/e5EI0Lx6YV2ZXpTlyq34xZk@Vw14hirg99yp/g9o2f1dH5TEYHttv94F8bpqrXGBzAa9ib/zK1kMwWl4v@MrxUTtf4yBhcwFi68PhSnK79xIU27wlCRtG0YEkVg86DAJYEHEfaUyoX3nH5bimJEkubKIrpakKyVTEWlrkSHXghrLKH2tRj31/4iR4a0DB@8kKkZTd6fVuVbSrPCl6@AA)

### Explanation

`??<` and `??>` are trigraphs for `{` and `}` respectively

```c
A,B;      // A will track the minimum, B will track the maximum
D(*C){    // D() will traverse C updating the values of A and B
  *C<A?   // if current character < A
    A=*C  //   update A with it's value
  :*C>B?  // else if current character > B
    B=*C  //   update B with it's value
  :0;     // else, do nothing
  *++C?   // if we're not at the end of the string
    D(C)  //   call D recursively with the next character
  :0;     // else, do nothing
}         // end D()
C(*C){    // C() takes the string, which is also where we'll store the output
  A=B=*C; // initialize A and B with the first character in C
  D(C);   // call D
  *C=B-A; // store the range (max - min) in the out argument
}         // end C()
```

Comment: You can reduce the overall score to 138 if you use trigraphs: ...

Comment: https://tio.run/##pZJRb5swEMef8ae4tuowhExR9zYCqMqyrVLRpLFqD@sUecYm1oyJDC1bq3z1sTOsUartbQiB/ffd/3dnm8@5ZqYaBh7VUR5LGhZRaIMsW8rG0jrJk7CIOX5mszjgyzqrE/6ap3mW438RhzbJ53WcZelwVgqpjIDNm/Xby5vrT5viw83H1ZqcKcP1XSlg2Xalal5u0@eSVt@eaz3fMuskct@oknSi7eiobToI@zYgj8RTpgMrupgQT9K@jeAFzoKYeDuLS5Ke@ue69WGewnl5a04jcDFTyJ4QDCE1U4Y6wOj35N/zyDHQqFUPAgXOdoyr7ick8OoiAi0MjhaO27c4qpnWDaeHqBBcXiPHQseordICsH4MrkTnMDTAcjiksAgA0Z6SQEff5EALUJ4AVkwEV/8RJoGL4G/YaOVQCVz7t8af/NHoC/p/hVFd@LHTpl11aTg5dOV5exC6Fcd5s5nL7Pm4SvAlh4pPkqce/oE4IrgcaYWgf@rEg7izxgH3w3uB/UXwubG6PCHMPWTV4D1412hJio7x77D@gftmKkEui9XVFfnfq/qLS82qdph3VlWW7bbtbw

Comment: @DigitalTrauma nice one, braces are really expensive

Comment: [score: 111](https://tio.run/##NY7NTsMwEITP9lMskYocx5Fyxk2sJLWgErceOEAPUf5qYeLKsQCp6qsT7BL2NDvzaXfatNXNNC5LySq@I1TGQmyp3JaizKl8oLKoRBVUxmmSSLEjMvZaiEJ6mNE68GUeEB4yTuu8SssALGpy@KNRE/k0qovxBSPvUHD97F6PkMMFMELP0VOvtWHwYqzu7iJ285owq65N18Oj0cO6H1zTvoP8bk@@eL@a5aHe7286w@jKMRqMBeL/gcoz/vdTHTmoJIkx8lVCF7C98yiSZM3ZvXfiYJ2tzwcSbfQMaQGb7m2K2P8ZBit2xdflpx10M85L6qwabXM@efn1Cw)

Comment: @jdt that's interesting, I didn't know you could do that

Comment: It's all about the scope, but I think this is question is the only example where doing something is [this](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI02zOhNC5pUopNlaWqflF2lA2IbWaTaGBtZp2tqaIMK6tvY/SCI3MTNPQ5OrmoszTcPQQNOaq/Y/AA) is usefull.

Answer (score 6):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + GNU utilities, 52 bytes + 92 range = 144

```bash
od -An -w1 -td1 -v|sort -n|sed -n '1p;$p'|dc -e??r-p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY2xDoIwFAD3fsWTYLrYgZmBEEKUxMHIYBwr7yHEpq9piTj03yv@gjfccsM9dJjSOs2GwJPGEpCF87NdRpD7ICHLr@3lfM8gJkZQtQW1FqAW3PSOgf0CysZAW7MgC1fmTkYcQFFVeeUSsqV0ImP4ADf2BndC/xANI8GRzSj6RQ8vaD/DpO2TRN03XSf@mYkv)

Answer (score 4):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 13 bytes + 39 = 52

```
a:A^aMXaADMNa
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJhOkFeYU1YYUFETU5hIiwiIiwiIiwiXCJIZWxsbywgV29ybGQhXCIiXQ==)

#### Explanation

A straight code-golf solution to the challenge might look like this:

```
A*:a;Ma-Na
   a        First command-line argument
A*          Get ASCII value of each character
  :         and assign that list of integers back to a
    ;       Statement separator
        Na  Minimum of a
      a-    Subtract that from each element in a
     M      and take the maximum of the resulting list
```

This gets a score of 65. The `a` for getting the command-line argument and `A` for taking ASCII values are both necessary, so to improve the score we'll need to look at the characters with ASCII values less than `A`.

The smallest character is `*`, which we can get rid of by splitting the string into a list of characters with `^` and passing that list to `A` directly:

```
A*:a
 ->
a:A^a
```

The next-smallest character is `-`, which we can get rid of by using the absolute difference operator `AD` instead. Then we have to rearrange a bit more to avoid needing a space; we'll use the old `MX` and `MN` operators for max and min instead of the newer `M` and `N`.

```
Ma-Na
 ->
MXaADMNa
```

(We could also keep using `M`, but since it also requires a semicolon to parse correctly, the score is the same if we replace it with `MX` which doesn't need the semicolon.)

Answer (score 4):

## [Alumin](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Alumin), <s>36</s> 19 bytes + <s>22</s> 20 = <s>58</s> 39

```
idiqdhhhwrvsruripkc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8wpzc3M@/8/MyWzMCUjI6O8qKy4qLQosyA7GasgAA)

Both the right language for the job<s>, and horribly inefficient at it!</s> Turns out, I'm just an inefficient thinker!

### Explanation

```
idiqdhhhwrvsruripkc
                       explanation           | stack
id                     take input, duplicate | MAX MIN
  iq           ip      while input > 0       | MAX MIN in
    d                    duplicate           | MAX MIN in in
     hhhw                grab top 3          | MAX [ MIN in in ]
         r               reverse stack       | MAX [ in in MIN ]
          v              get lesser of two   | MAX [ in MIN' ]
           s             ungrab              | MAX in MIN'
            r            reverse stack       | MIN' in MAX
             u           get greater of two  | MIN' MAX'
              r          reverse stack       | MAX' MIN'
                         (this gives us a better score than using `y` to swap 2)
                      loop finishes          | MAX MIN -1
                 k    discard eof            | MAX MIN
                  c   subtract               | MAX-MIN
```

### Explanation (Old)

```
hqidrlhcwrspkrklhhgwfufsykrlhcwfvfsc
h                                     push 1 (to start loop)
 q         p                          input loop
  id                                  take input, duplicate
    r                                 reverse stack
     lhc                              stack length - 1
        wrs                           reverse that many elements off the stack
                                      this has the effect of pushing two copies of the input
            krk                       pop trailing EOF twice
               lhhg                   stack length / 2
                   w                  grab that many elements into a new stack
                    fuf               fold over maximum
                       sykr           place on bottom stack, remove initial 1
                           lhc        stack length - 1
                              w       grab that many elements as before
                               fvf    fold over minimum
                                  sc  push and subtract
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), score 56 (length 6, range 50)

```matlab
@range
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/foSgxLz31f5qCrUJiXrE1V5qGukdqTk6@jkJ4flFOiqK6JkgoEQQgTOf8lFQF9/ycNAg3uCQxOVvBtSI5A2QORMwx2NnTE8KEGK@u@R8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), <s>9</s> 12 bytes + <s>56</s> <s>49</s> 38 = 50

```
;*;-;o;/;\;`<@@o;/_$;`$$
```

This corresponds to the [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html) program with nibbles:

```
6 a 6 9 6 e 6 a 6 b 6 e 4 d 4 e 6 a 5 3 6 d 7 3
```

Which, paired-up into bytes, gives

```
6a 69 6e 6a 6b 6e 4d 4e 6a 53 6d 73
```

which can be read-out as a string (with the same ASCII values)

```
jinjknMNjSms
```

with ASCII range 115 (`73`) - 77 (`4d`) = 38.

---

**How?**
We start from a straightforward code-golf solution to the question: `` -o/\;`<$$o/ `` (5.5 bytes, 11 nibbles):

```
-o/\;`<$@o/
-                   # subtract
 o                  #   character value of
  /                 #   fold over
   \                #     reverse of
    ;               #     (save)
     `<             #     sorted
       @            #     input
        $           #   returning left element each time
                    #   (so the fold returns the first element)
                    # from
         o          #   character value of
          /         #   fold over
                    #   (implicit) saved sorted input
                    #   (implicit) returning left element each time
```

The nibbles are slightly re-arranged in the final program, since the 2-nibble 'sort' function ( `` `< ``) wraps around its argument (here `$`).  Thus, the paired-up nibbles from this are:

```
-o /\ ;` @< $o /    # program code (in final order)
9e ab 6e 4d 3e a    # nibbles
```

We can reduce the range of bytes by inserting 'save' operators (`;`, nibble `6`) to shift high-valued nibbles into the least-significant-nibble position of each byte.
This doesn't affect the output, but we need to override the final implicit variable to account for the saved (but ignored) values.  Hence:

```
;- ;o ;/ ;\ ;` @< $o ;/ ;$   # program code (in final order), with final variable changed to ;$
69 6e 6a 6b 6e 4d 3e 6a 63   # nibbles
```

Modifying both folds (so returning right element `@` instead of left element `$`) avoids the lowest byte `3e`, but unfortunately outputs a negated value.
So we multiply (and save: `;*`) the negated value by its own sign (also saved: `` ;`$ ``): this corrects the output, introducing a new highest byte of `73`, but the overall score is still reduced.

[image]

Comment: @TheThonnu - The actual program corresponds to the nibbles in the .nbb file.  The string that you've calculated from is just a human-readable form (which uses one character for every nibble of the program).  The bytes of the program that you've scored were hex values ```69 6a 6c 3e 38 34 6a 4a 34```, giving the all-ASCII string ```ijl>84jJ4``` with range 56.

Comment: @TheThonnu [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8KQt.png) is an example of using the raw bytes of the (now updated) program directly.  Obviously, the program is unintelligible for a human like this (since the characters represent pairs of nibbles that are smashed-together), but this is what it looks like if interpreted as characters...

Answer (score 3):

## [Excel](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/excel), score = <sup><s>103</s></sup> 94 (length 46, range 48)

-9 score thanks to [Engineer Toast](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38183/engineer-toast)

```
=LET(A,CODE(RIGHT(A1,ROW(A:A))),MAX(A)-MIN(A))
```

[image]

Comment: Same range but shorter length (46) by abusing CODE() which will convert only the first character of a multi-character string: `=LET(A,CODE(RIGHT(A1,ROW(A:A))),MAX(A)-MIN(A))`

Answer (score 3):

## [Terse](https://gymhgy.github.io/TerseLang/), 7 bytes + 6769 = 6776

```
找没最手样找到
```

[Try it here](https://gymhgy.github.io/TerseLang/?code=wGm9voTAag&in=IuaJvuayoeacgOaJi-agt-aJvuWIsCI)

Could be worse.

```
找　　　　　　　　Char codes
　没　　　　　　　Maximum, after
　　最手　　　　　　Squaring and then square root (identity)
　　　　样　　　　Subtract
　　　　　找到　　Minimum
```

Comment: what kind of wretched 残体字 programming language is this ??

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto let's say I did not have readability in mind when I designed the stuff

Comment: that's not my point - i could read simplified. the question was about why use a character set invented by CCP instead of one that has existed since 嬴政 統一六國 文字 ?

Comment: Unfortunately this program can't handle strings of length 1, for which it should return \$0\$.

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), 22 bytes + 80 = 102

```
+s=-(-(extrema(s)...))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBgqWlJWm6Ftu0i211NXQ1UitKilJzEzWKNfX09DQ1IZI3G6OVPFJzcvJ1FMLzi3JSFJV0lBUULIy4lBJBAMyDAwMuJef8lFQF9_ycNISMuSWXUnBJYnK2gmtFckZiXnoqxAwLLiXHYGdPTyVkIxQMLbhi9WrsCooy80py8h51zNCGOATmWgA)

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, score: 134 (54 bytes)

```java
s->s.chars().max().orElse(0)-s.chars().min().orElse(0)
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##dVLBTuMwEL33KwafbKU1e0IrKlaCqLAcFlYExIFFq8FxGhfXruxpAaF@e7GT0q1WIpEmmTfjN@@NPMMVjmb180ZZjBF@oXHvAwDjSIcGlYarnHYAKF5RMG4KUYwTuB6kEAnJKLgCByebOPoRpWoxRC7kHF9T9GFio@bfxGivYtx@ZTPORIvlk01EW76VNzXMk5jtyIdHFNQG/xJh8qr0gox3vbDGB77CAKQjlRj1sdMv8Hnonf3U1voh3Ptg6wM2ZJif9C19reHC2yb9V4TqOfO26KY6AadVeXnJ1qIbAFC9RdJz6ZckF4mXrOOf0wp2DKxwUu0QITo7AFmUylNO4J8kPkv7ls542Rir5XkKUQaN9am1Z2@J47@G30it9A1n8lBmMpmMMyGGsGvrlqpJJhOuxlCXfR7l3e353@9CxoU1xNkfx8TD0eN48IWh3FDkCWK8Ux90XFrK@pO/vVq@C1a7KbWp1qnqMy6@pq/K65tJ3hXvWYv@iCgYcFZsMZbeHi@YYNtLtt58AA) (also contains code to extract the lambda function from the code-block and calculate its score: `(max_codepoint - min_codepoint) + length`).

Not too much too improve unfortunately.

- We could change the `x` to `\u0078`, but unfortunately the next highest codepoint then becomes `u` which isn't too much lower than `x`, so the +5 in byte-count is higher than the -3 in codepoint, giving a +2 in score instead of decrease: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##dVLBThsxEL3nK6Y@2drE5NQiIirRVaAcSiu2iAOgyvV6sw6OHdmTUITy7el4N4QIiV3J9rwZv/dm5Llaq9G8ftxqp1KCH8r6lwGA9Whio7SBqxx2AGheYbR@BklMCNwMaEmo0Gq4Ag@n2zT6mqRuVUxcyIW6X43HX47pGOLUJcPHYnSQtv4ws51ktuXqryO2Hek62BoW5Gine/egBLYxPCWY/tNmiTb43l0TIl@rCGgSliqZE2@e4PXSC/tunAtDuA3R1Z/YkKn80V6G2sBFcA2dK1T6MfO2ys8MAWdVeXnJNqITAKieE5qFDCuUS@JF5/mrWsFOgBVe6j0iRNcOQDals8opvFnicxq69DbIxjojz2lJMhpVnzn37Zk43hX8UtjK0HAmj2Qmk9Q4E2II@7JuqAYlNeFrFeuyj5O8@X3@51jItHQWObv3TNx9fpgMPmgoFxRZQUz27qNJK4fZP/V3kMsPwhk/w5Zynas@4uJj@qr8eT3Ns@I9a9FfEQUDzoodxujv8YIJtntpm@1/).
- Using a regular for-loop requires both `{}` and a space, so the difference of the max-min codepoints would widen on both ends. And in addition it's longer anyway: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##dVLBjtMwEL33KwafbKU1nBBtNotKtAt7yIIIKw6lQsZxmnQdu7KnXaqq317spFsE0iaS7Xl6897M2GuxE5N19XiSWngPhWjNYQTQGlSuFlLBfQx7ACSVjXCLpWdpwI6jsHgU2Eq4BwPZyU@uD5HXZdPpdFxkb9LaOtpnzjw7dJm86t7LWZcWmbwuwqlIj07h1hkoJl16PKVRcrP9pYPkWXln2wq6UBUt0bVmtVgKho2zTx5ufku1wdaaocLotRMOUHnMhVczo57gOelAPimt7Ri@W6erV2RMRPzCnttKwUer63AuUcjHqNsIs1IBmJf53R05st4AoNx7VB23W@SboIva0Ge3hMyAJIbLC8LR5mFcc@fEnjLG@uYAYokyembwt0C6DtfATWt53WrFb8PiuVOimmv9YR8U/yN8EdhwW1PCX/MoxsMYCGNjuNDiTXmFPLRkKuGqfIg9f/h2@/Md436jW6TkhyFs8XaZjl5oLxKS6MDSS/VO@a3GWH/odnD/p9P08mC0MitsArNnDRFlL5uV@eevN3GOdPBIhhSWEKAkOWMk/AOeEEbOT/F4@gM).

**Explanation:**

```java
s->            // Method with String parameter and integer return-type
  s.chars()    //  Convert the String to an IntStream of codepoint integers
   .max()      //  Get the maximum of these codepoints
   .orElse(0)  //  Convert the OptionalInt to an int
               //  (`.orElse(0)` is 1 byte shorter than `.getAsInt()`)
  -            //  And subtract
   s.chars().min().orElse(0)
               //  The same to get the minimum codepoint
```

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>12 bytes + 86 = 98</s> 13 bytes + 56 = 69

h/t @isaacg

```
+/1_-':@/1<:\
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs9LWN4zXVbdy0De0sYrh4srPSbHS1deo0bdW09d0iLHi4gqx0lDySM3JyVcIzy/KSVFU4lJQUFBKBAIIyzk/JVXBPT8nDcINLklMzlZwrUjOSMxLT4WIOQY7e3pCmEhmx1hBhFBcEKOkycWVph7CBQBShCQG)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes + 32 = 35

```
Sds
```

#### Explanation

```
Sds
S     % Sort implicit input
 d    % Difference between adjacent elements
  s   % Sum the values
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Pzil@P9/dY/UnJx8HYXw/KKcFEV1AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page) + 149 = 154

<sup>I think this is about as good as it's going to get in Jelly due to the distance between `O` (unavoidable as it's the only way to get the ordinals of the input string) and the large ordinals of Unicode characters representing the bytes for mapping and getting maximums and minimums, index into a list etc.</sup>

```
OÞOIS
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of characters and yields the range size as an integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9//8Dx/z@D///@rewAF8nUUwvOLclIU1QE)**

#### How?

```
OÞOIS - Link: list of characters        (ordinal)
 Þ    - sort by:                        (222)
O     -   ordinal value                 (79)
  O   - ordinal values                  (79)
   I  - forward differences             (73)
    S - sum                             (83)
                                        ----
                                         222
                                       -  73
                                        ====
                                         149
```

Comment: Yeah, the golflangs with custom codepages are probably going to struggle on this challenge...

Comment: @TheThonnu strictly speaking the code _is_ bytes (the Unicode characters are just an abstraction for ease of reading), but I think this may still be best using that measure too (with a score of \$5 + 63 = 68\$).

Comment: Would it help if you used literal UTF-8 bytes and ran with `fu` or `eu`?

Comment: @Steffan Do you mean some lower scoring text that when read as bytes and treated as UTF-8 ends up as valid Jelly code? I have no idea how to approach that.

Comment: No, I mean take the literal indices in the Jelly codepage and interpret it as a UTF-8 byte sequence, then run with Jelly's `fu`/`eu` flags. I thought it might be a lower score. (In other words, use the indices in the Jelly codepage, and have the program use those indices as UTF-8 byte sequence.)

Comment: @Steffan the `u` flag will ignore any UTF-8 characters that are not on the code page and use the remaining ones, so how can code running with `u` help? The raw bytes running _without_ `u` would score \$5+63=68\$. Maybe I'm missing something - are you able to produce an example of what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I had it backwards lol. Yes, what i meant is running without the `u` flag. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6AoM68kTUEppsLELabC0ARCm1jGVJgaKynYKZSk5hbolVSUcGWl5uRUKqTlwUUUlDyAQvk6CuH5RTkpikpcqckZ@WBCQSk4Ob8o1UpBRUNDRQNTY0JyYgmcl6CpoA1UWJ6soJusYAMT1dTUhBpYUZECV/v/PwA "Bash – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal) -v, 35 bytes, score 61

```
castminusordceilceil[q]ordminmin[q]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z85sbgkNzOvtDi/KCU5NTMHhKMLY4E8oCgQAdnEKdItywEA) Abusing Charcoal's verbose parser again. In order for it to recognise `q` as a variable name I can't follow it with a letter, so the next nearest suitable characters are the list delimiters. I've also used `ceil` instead of `max` to avoid using an `x`; this costs 2 bytes but overall saves 1 from my score. Normally the program would be written like this:

```
Print(Cast(Minus(Ordinal(Maximum(q)), Ordinal(Minimum(q)))));
```

The best I could do in succinct Charcoal was a score of 10135:

```
⭆ψ⁻℅⌈θ℅⌊θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaFTqKPhm5pUWa/gXpWTmJeZo@CZWZOaW5moUamrqKMAFM/NggkBg/f//o7Vt5zseNe5@1NL6qKfj3A4w3XVux3/dshwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: The limiting factors here are the Greek letter `θ` needed for the two occurrences of the input variable (the only other input method uses `Ｓ` which has a ridiculously high Unicode code point of 65531) and the `⭆` used to stringify the result (again, `Ｉ` would have had far too high a code point).

```
 ψ          Predefined string null character
⭆           Map over characters and join
     θ      Input string
    ⌈       Maximium
   ℅        Ordinal
  ⁻         Minus
        θ   Input string
       ⌊    Minimum
      ℅     Ordinal
            Implicitly print
```

If using bytes from Charcoal's code page was allowed, its score would "only" be 210:

```
ＳαＩ⁻℅⌈α℅⌊α
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0JLikKDMvXSNR05orAMgq0XBOLC7R8M3MKy3W8C9KycxLzNHwTazIzC3NBSrS1FGAC2bmwQSBwPr//8NTDy883Hlo7aFmqcMLDzVLHl74X7csBwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: The limiting factors here are that `⌊` (`Minimum`) is byte index 25 while `α` (variable `a`) is byte index 225, although I did reduce my score by 14 by taking the input into `α` rather than the default input of `θ` (variable `q`, byte index 241).

```
Ｓ           Input as a string
 α          Store in variable `a`
      α     Input string
     ⌈      Maximum
    ℅       Ordinal
   ⁻        Subtract
         α  Input string
        ⌊   Minimum
       ℅    Ordinal
  Ｉ         Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes + 67 = score 73

```
C:G$g-
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiQzpHJGctIiwiIiwiXCJIZWxsbywgV29ybGQhXCJcblwiQzpHJGctXCJcblwiYVwiIl0=)

Comment: Why the additional `f`? It seems like the older 6 byte version both meets all test cases and has a lower score

Comment: @emirps it only works because of an update made a couple days ago that make `G` and `g` on numbers be a no-op instead of erroring. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes + [63](https://tio.run/##RYy9CsIwGEX3PMW3NcHaxS2iUAShIDjUxfGz6U8gfyQZWl8@pgjtdjnn3uuWOFlzSklqZ32EsATi4QIK9UcgKA4aZ6oYHEFLkwOxuw0clAyRanTUelFCYIwMu585eGrpnKnMNH9XIQppKt@joIxghgOVjKh105s1Oi9NpEXd3poGPJqx50UJuIlHb8Y4rUxt7GUjKgid9f/yQbGU6vZ7tef7@6m7Hw) = 74

```
ASz>o;FYOmc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3zG4yi7f2i3SPzf5////Hqk5Ofk6CuH5RTkpigA)

```
ASz>o;FYOmc
         m   # map over input
          c  #   getting character values
        O    # and sort into ascending order;
  z          # now, zip together
   >         # getting differences
 S           #   the sorted list itself
             # and
    o;       #   the single-element list of
      F      #   fold over the sorted list
       Y     #   getting pairwise maxima
A            # finally, get the average
             # of the resulting single-element list.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 42 bytes + 80 = 122

```javascript
s=>Math.max(...b=Buffer(s))-Math.min(...b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc/BbsIwDAbgO0/hRRwSAWHbhW5SkQChwWGnHnYlhKQthBiSDDFNffauHSBV8dH@7F/ei4vw0pWnMLK4U7VOa59OP0Uo@FFcKed8m86/tVaOesZGt0Fp/weslmg9GsUN5nSTSXTqHfq/FlLQPGAWXGlzyrhRNg9FBdufoDwMGnJuCe0iVjWtdncA52rDer3ubU3JShmDQ/hCZ3ZPBBiD8RiS15iJtgg86saeY7VoXoUPNJp01OQtZlkQ8gDLqyyEzRW5ZyYxm2WL9TrOfEnqPw)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), score 70 (16 bytes, range 54)

```
[:+/2-/\a.I.]\:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03B1koh2kpb30hXPyZRz1MvNsYq9n9qcka@QpqCukdqTk6@jkJ4flFOiqL6fwA)

- `]` `\:` `]`: Pass the input (using the identity function [`]`](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d500.htm)) on both sides of [`\:`](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d431.htm) to sort it in descending order.
- `a.` `I.`: For each character of the sorted input, find its index in the ["alphabet"](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dadot.htm); at least on TIO's setup, this contains all of [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1) in order, which includes ASCII. Thus, this produces the ASCII values of the characters, while keeping the highest used character lower than the straightforward method of `3` [`u:`](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/duco.htm) would.
  ([`I.`](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dicapdot.htm) would also take the following index if a character is not found, but that never happens; it was chosen over [`i.`](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/didot.htm) to reduce the highest used character.)
- `2-/\`: For each length-2 subarray (from the `2` and [`\`](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d430.htm)), subtract the second value from the first ([`-`](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d120.htm) [`/`](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d420.htm)).
- `[:` `+/`: Take the sum ([`+`](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d100.htm) [`/`](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d420.htm)) of the values, using [`[:`](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d502.htm) to do so monadically.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 8 bytes + 70 = 78

```
ia0I-s>l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z8z0cBTt9gu5///4JLE5GwF14rkjMS89FQA)

I found a shorter program, but the character range of the code was big enough that it had a higher total score.

```
ia        - read STDIN onto stack as codepoints, sort the stack
  0I      - copy the bottom of the stack to the top
    -     - subtract to get the range
     s>l  - save result, switch to clean stack, load result
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://www.raku.org/), 25 bytes

ASCII range: 88
Length: 25
Total score: 113

```perl6
[-] @_.ords.minmax[*-1,0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X1yapJCmUP0/WjdWwSFeL78opVgvNzMvN7EiWkvXUMcg9n@ttUJBUWZeCVCZukdqTk6@jkJ4flFOiqL6fwA)

Comment: Note the custom scoring criteria - you need to add ASCII range of your code to the score

Comment: @KirillL. Got it, thanks.

Comment: By our site consensus, you can't take input from a variable (`@_` in this case). You can take input from a function: `{[-] .ords.minmax[*-1,0]}` for a score of 118. You can also use a full program: `put [-] get.ords.minmax[*-1,0]` which is also 118 score.

Comment: @Steffan Thanks for your input.  Is it acceptable with some like [this](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X61QnFj5P1o3VkEvvyilWC83My83sSJaS9dQxyD2f61CWn6RgrpHak5Ovo5CeH5RToqiuo6CeiIIgBjO@SmpCu75OWkgTnBJYnK2gmtFckZiXnoqSMQx2NnTU/0/AA)?

Comment: Sorry, no, because you're still taking input from a variable (`$_`).

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 98 score (18 bytes)

ASCII range: 80
Length: 18
Total score: 98

```cs
s=>s.Max()-s.Min()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7LCsIwEEX3/Yoxq4Q@EJdqC1J8FCoIFVyHJG2DJZEmlYL47bUPoYizGc6Zy3CZ8ZmR3aFRbGtsLVXhgVQ2ghzCzoSRCc60xcTvt1SYdBvnKozF6CSqSiPygx7cdF3xxazpMDPGmgs46iqfVWYpu8O@ZSVVhZj9LouTZMAv/1cZj08tOYyJqXzf/dFY8nIAbrW0IpVK4NG5aI1chIIL5anILV4t/dEHqVCFLYmbTznSv313Hw)

- -27 score thanks to Kevin Cruijssen for the tip to use C# Interactive

---

## [C# (Visual C# Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 125 score (36 bytes)

ASCII range: 89
Length: 36
Total score: 125

```cs
s=>s.Max()-s.Min()
```

If we're going traditional through the compiler then we have to include an extra 18 bytes for `using System.Linq;`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc1LCoMwEIDhfU8xdZWAegGrUKQPoULBhesQow1NE@rEYimePY3FvZ3NwPD9DMeII3cDSt1B9UYrHvFF6mcCXDFEuMIH0DIrObyMbKBkUhPqj4s9Dprv0PY@D0Fqm0ELKThMM4xLNhIa@T0nLtksSW40GiXiupdW@F@CtCQ4C6VMQOkfKoTa9KrZrmo2z6rKTSPgZFS7KivL@B0OI78x3YlVvq/yovipCSb3BQ)

Comment: 98 score (18 `length` + 80 `max-min`) by using the `Visual C# Interactive Compiler` as language, so you won't need the `Using`: [try it online](https://tio.run/##ZY7LCsIwEEX3/Yoxq4Q@EJdqC1J8FCoIFVyHJG2DJZEmlYL47bUPoYizGc6Zy3CZ8ZmR3aFRbGtsLVXhgVQ2ghzCzoSRCc60xcTvt1SYdBvnKozF6CSqSiPygx7cdF3xxazpMDPGmgs46iqfVWYpu8O@ZSVVhZj9LouTZMAv/1cZj08tOYyJqXzf/dFY8nIAbrW0IpVK4NG5aI1chIIL5anILV4t/dEHqVCFLYmbTznSv313Hw).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Ah good tip, it's been a while so a little rusty on some of the tips and tricks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 8 bytes + 34 = 42

```
+F.+CDCM
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X9tNT9vZxdn3/38lGFMJAA)

- `CM`: Map to ASCII value
- `CD`: Sort (equivalent to `S`)
- `.+`: Deltas (Differences between consecutive elements, all nonegative because of sort)
- `+F`: Sum (equivalent to `s`)

Using `.+` is golfier than `h` and `e`, and also stays within the established ASCII value range.

Comment: Using deltas is a neat trick.  K doesn’t have a handy sort so it ends up longer.  f:+/1_-':@/1<:\.

Comment: Ah, but it lowers the score!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 12 bytes + 52 = 64

```
)**J>]\/<].-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/V/9X1NLy8suNkbfJlZP939teM5/j9ScnHwuZGEA)

```
)**  # Map to char code
J    # Duplicate
>]   # Maximum
\/   # Swap
<]   # Minimum
.-   # Difference
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 31 bytes + 85 = 116

```
ToCharacterCode@s//Max@#-Min@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n1icnJkZlJiXnhpdHB9cUpSZlx6rYGX7PyTfOSOxKDG5JLXIOT8l1aFYX983scJBWdc3M89BWQ1Zn5JHak5Ovo5CeH5RToqiUqy@fgDQmBIuZCWJIIBdCmS8gnt@Thp26eCSxORsBdeK5AwQH7sax2BnT0@41H8A)

Comment: This challenge has its own scoring criterion (not code-golf) so your score is [116](https://tio.run/##RYzBCsIwEETv@YoFQRNs9eCtIFR6KtiT/YHVRBtIsmWTQ/v1NUWot@G9mRnnNFC4LIv1I3GCOEfBcAWH/qkRXAUeJ@kUlOBtyEHQ38YKnI1JehwlsS4gKiXefz9VwJLklKnNNH@fYtI2nNiglkpghm9plXDrxoQ1jmxDkofbo2lbYAwfUx0KwE3cTfikYWVuYz0ldBBfxL/y0all6akZkPGVDDekTR3P5w6neld2NtS7/Rc)

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `GB`, 2 + 24 = 26

```
G_
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPUdfJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9SGVsbG8mZmxhZ3M9R0I=)

Port of lyxal's Vyxal answer.

##### Explanation

```python
G_  # Implicit input
    # Convert to codepoints
G   # Maximum codepoint
 _  # Subtract each input codepoint
    # Find the maximum
    # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Sequences](https://github.com/nayakrujul/sequences), score = 73 + 4.12 = 77.12

<sub>(Sequences uses the 96 printable ASCII characters as its codepage, so the byte count of this program is \$5\log_{256}(96) \approx 4.12\$)</sub>

```
`vMm-
```

#### Explanation

```python
`vMm-  # Implicit input as a string
`v     # Get the ASCII values of the input string in a list
  M    # Get the maximum value of that list
   m   # Get the minimum value of that list
    -  # And subtract to find the range
       # (implicit output)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 39 + 80 = 119

```python
print(ord(max(s:=input()))-ord(min(s)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dY8xTgMxEEV7n2JwE1vZTUGFVtoCRQhSb5HarG1i4R1btoOSs6RJA1yDa-Q2zO6SdEz3x-9__zl9xWPZBTx_W2iBc_65L7Z-uCxiclhESFoM6iBy0zqM-yKklPW0dCgyiT_8h5yrXJKLQjI2e3nXh2QaXoE3KKysgC9JXCOtlFDDNYsUvbc3GJYg_iUl_eGGGFKBfMyM2ZDAOzTgcFxQEe2wYUAztabLvBpetWom7FZ0BMyH8pQ533G-3L8Y70MF25C8vmNqHLYO2sBz8JZ1RfXv8HTodwrfDHvs1pvNbP0F)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 26 bytes + 80 = 106

-2 bytes thanks to [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)

```ruby
->s{y=s.bytes;y.max-y.min}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuha7dO2Kqytti_WSKktSi60r9XITK3SBZGZeLUTBlgIFt2glj9ScnHwdhfD8opwURaVYiNSCBRAaAA)

Comment: Same ASCII range, two bytes shorter: `->s{y=s.bytes;y.max-y.min}`

Comment: @Steffan Cool, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 27 bytes + 84 = score 111

```haskell
_?s=(maximum$s)-(minimum$s)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8FN7dzEzDzbgqLMvBIFFQUNe00FA4VoQwNDHQUoYaGjYG4EZBgaxi4tLUnTtdgdb19sq5GbWJGZW5qrUqypq5GbmQdlQ1QsgFJQGgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 21 bytes + 87 = 108

```ruby
:bytes|:-%[:max,:min]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWW62SKktSi2usdFWjrXITK3SscjPzYiFyWwoU3KKVPFJzcvJ1FMLzi3JSFJWgUgsWQGgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [q](https://code.kx.com/q), 19 bytes

```
(-/)7h$(max;min)@\:
```

## k4, 17 bytes

```
(-/)7h$(|/;&/)@\:
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the range of your source code to calculate your final score...

Answer (score 1):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), score = 15 + 79 = 94

```
[:(>./-<./)3&u:
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxPtpKw05PX9dGT1_TWK3UCiJ6s1-TKzU5I19BPTg5vygVolvJSkFDWUFbIU1TQR1NlzpEdZqCukdqTk6-jkJ4flFOiiJCOBEEEFzn_JRUBff8nDSEUHBJYnK2gmtFckZiXnoqQtwx2NnTUx3irAULIDQA)

```
[:(>./-<./)3&u:
[:               NB. enforce f (g y)
           3&u:  NB. convert string to list of char codes
  (       )      NB. monadic fork
       <./       NB. min
   >./           NB. max
      -          NB. subtract
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 29 bytes + 77 = 106

```
\(a)diff(range(utf8ToInt(a)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhZ7YzQSNVMy09I0ihLz0lM1gIIWIfmeeSVAYU1NiJqb1WkaSh6pOTn5Ogrh-UU5KYpKmsoKCgoWRlxAiUQQgAjAgAFI3Dk_JVXBPT8nDSFnbgmSCC5JTM5WcK1IzgDZCJa1sABJOAY7e3qimmRoAXHCggUQGgA)

Seems that most golfy approach has also the lowest score, since we need to use `utf8ToInt()` and it has the range of 77 by itself.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), score: <s>158</s> 124 (4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage))

```
Ç{¥O
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cHv1oaX@//97pObk5OsohOcX5aQoAgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/w@3Vh5b6/9f5H63kkZqTk6@jEJ5flJOiqKSjlAgCQNo5PyVVwT0/Jw3IDi5JTM5WcK1IzkjMS08FCjgGO3t6KsUCAA) or [verify its score](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fyTk/JbUgPzOvpFghM0/BwNTRydBVITUvOT8lMy/dSkHJ/ui@I22ewdm2XEq@iRW6uZl5IMHqQ0v9gSI@qXnpJRkgAc9020Pb7LmUgpPzi1JBAtr2//8fbgepAwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ç     # Get a list of codepoint integers of the (implicit) input-string
 {    # Sort them
  ¥   # Get the forward differences/deltas
   O  # Sum those together
      # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), score: <s>200</s> 191 (<s>4</s> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)†)

<sup>*†: MathGolf uses [Code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Character_set)*.</sup>

```
$_╙\╓-
```

Increased the byte-count to slightly improve the score, but this is pretty hopeless.. The `ord` builtin `$` is too far apart from most of the other useful builtins like `min`(`╓`)/`max`(`╙`)/`sum`(`Σ`)..

Input as a list of characters.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/18l/tHUmTGPpk7W/f8/Wt1DXUc9FYhzoDgfiEFQAYjDofwiqFwKECuqx3JFqycCWagYJOoMVZ8CNRNkhjtUDKQ/DawqGMgqgepLBuJsqEpXIK6AimVA5fOAOB1sGkinI5AF0g2yxxOMYwE)

**Explanation:**

```python
$       # Get the codepoint integers of each character in the (implicit) input-list
 _      # Duplicate it
  ╙     # Pop and push its maximum
   \    # Swap
    ╓   # Pop and push its minimum
     -  # Subtract this minimum from the maximum
        # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), Score: 50 bytes + 74 = 124

```
0ff*i:0(ee+*98++0.:@:@$:@)?$?>@$:@$:@(?$?>$30.@-n;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3yAtTSvTykAjNVVby9JCW9tAz8rBykHFykHTXsXeDsQAIg0QW8XYQM9BN8/6/3@P1JycfB2F8PyinBRFAA)

**Explanation**

Initialize **max = 0** and **min = 225**.
Then go through the input and update these values as needed.
At the end, print **max - min**.

**Range Max: n = 110**
We need **n** to print a number, so there isn't much we can do about this.

**Range Min: $ = 36**
**$** swaps the top 2 values of the stack. Replacing it could save **6** on the range, but since we are using it in 6 places it seems unlikely that could we could save on the score by the reducing the range.

**Code**

We've replaced **`~` = 126** with `?`  and **`r` = 114** with `@$` which saves **16** on the range at the cost of **3** bytes.

We've replaced the line feed **= 10** with jumps **`.` = 46** which saves **26** on the range at the cost of **6** bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-plF''` 33 bytes + 84 = 117

```perl
@_=map ord,sort@F;$_=$_[-1]-$_[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/98h3jY3sUAhvyhFpzi/qMTBzVol3lYlPlrXMFYXSBnE/lcGKgFJVask2tjaqSTVwtRjUeuRmpOTr6MQnl@Uk6LIlQgCXM75KakK7vk5aVzBJYnJ2QquFckZiXnpqVyOwc6enlwEHfAvv6AkMz@v@L9uQY6bujoA)

Comment: Note the custom scoring criteria - you need to add ASCII range of your code to the score

Comment: @KirillL.– edited now

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 70 range + 21 bytes = 91 score

```
math.statistics:range
```

[image]

Requires modernish Factor for fully-qualified word syntax, hence nothing online will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 39 bytes + 84 -> 123

```php
fn($s)=>max($a=unpack('C*',$s))-min($a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSZvs/LU9DpVjT1i43sUJDJdG2NK8gMTlbQ91ZS10HKK6pm5sJVJCo@d@aiys1OSNfQSUNKJmfkqrgnp@Tpq5p/R/OAQA)

EDIT: OK this time I admit functional approach is way better :P

OLD VERSION:

## [PHP](https://php.net/), -F 67 bytes + 78 -> 145

```php
for($n=INF;$c=ord($argn[$i++]);$c<$m?:$m=$c)$c>$n?:$n=$c;echo$m-$n;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchLCoAgFEbhrTT4B0a4gcwaBEaTNhANwl5C3ivW@jMnB74TrpCaLuQeHAVIj5NRsJrjJrDGk2a4qlrK/Br4robXsCVsC8qgDLXbi@ElSKXU87YXA9/Hx@F1TE@S5gc)

I wanted to give it a shot without arrays / min / max, in my traditional horrific-full of dollars-for loop Style and try to optimize for ASCII range rather. Stupid `$argn` cannot be in full caps. funny that it gives the same score like this (caps and no space nor brackets was the original plan):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), -F 88 bytes + 57 -> 145

```php
FOR($N=INF;$C=ORD($GLOBALS[STRTOLOWER(ARGN)][$I++]);$C<$M?:$M=$C)$C>$N?:$N=$C;ECHO$M-$N;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBCsIwFEXRrTh4g4TSDZjGUmMTC8n/kBYclM5UFMQEdP3GTC4cuPmRS9fnWstRgPREVsFojicB5/k4@Hmdl7iw58sYxRAdyW3F1DSbrGOH0O8RNIyEOYAqqEKN5swILUiVYtL1tnPpdf@l/H2m96e09g8)

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 11 chars + 9069-codepoint range = 9080.

### (In Dyalog one-byte encoding, range is 186 for a total of 197.)

```
(⌈/-⌊/)⎕UCS
```

[Try it online!](https://tryapl.org/?clear&q=(%E2%8C%88%2F-%E2%8C%8A%2F)%E2%8E%95UCS%27Hello%27%E2%8B%84((%E2%8C%88%2F-%E2%8C%8A%2F)%E2%8E%95UCS)%C2%A8%27Hello%2C%20World!%27%20%27aaaaa%27%20%27Code%20Golf%27%20%27Stack%20Exchange%27%20%27ASCII%27&run)

Comment: Don't forget to include the character code range of your code in your score for this challenge. There's a link to automatically score your submission above under "Scoring."

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 32 bytes + 88 = 120

```python
lambda x:ord(max(x))-ord(min(x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKr8oRSM3sUKjQlNTF8zOzAOx/xcUZeaVaKRpqHuk5uTk6yiE5xflpCiqA2UA)

Comment: This challenge has its own scoring criteria (rather than bytes), so your score is actually [120](https://tio.run/##RY@7DsIwDEX3fIU3HNF2YYvEgJgqscEPGNJHJCepkgzt1xcXpHY7Ote2rqeljDFc1tX5KaYCeckqwRWY/NsSsAFPM7KGGrwLAioeaTbALhf0NGFMtoKsteqPfDaQMOIs1omV200u1oUmdWRRKxLZo9OKt50ubDglFwqebs9720KiMHTmVAHtwaMLQxk3x7t7xUIM@RPTf/jMel33DtIMtyekRv1j@UP4Cw)

Comment: @TheThonnu Fixed! Mind upvoting my answer :)

Comment: Sorry, I've reached my daily voting limit. I will tomorrow.

Comment: @TheThonnu No problem, also on my other post :)

Comment: @TheThonnu Feel free whenever you have time :)

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 8 bytes, score 64

```
$(\)@-\;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPmvFFySmJyt4FqRnJGYl56q9F9FI0bTQTfG@v9/AA)

## Explanation

```
char     : usage                                : stack
$        : ($)ort the (implicit) input          : <sorted input>
 (       : take the first element out           : <sorted input> <first item>
  \      : swap the top two values of the stack : <first item> <sorted input>
   )     : last item                            : <first item> <sorted input> <last item>
    @    : rotate the stack                     : <sorted input> <last item> <first item>
     -   : subtract, giving us the range        : <sorted input> <range>
      \  : swap the top two values on the stack : <range> <sorted input>
       ; : discard the top of the stack         : <range>
(after which the stack is implicitly output)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 106 <s><sup>108</sup></s> bytes + 80 range = score 186 <s><sup>188</sup></s>

`-2 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat`

```java
s->(s.chars().reduce(0,(a,b)->a>0?b>a>>16?b*65792-a%256*255:b<a%256?a/65536*65792-b*255:a:b*65537)>>8)%256
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVDfT8IwEH6Gv@JcYtLCVhGyoagjhBglwac9@GB8uG0dDspG2o5IDH/7vI3pPbSX7679fmzxiN423dWHKlZ5AolCY@AN8wJ@@n2gygsrdYaJhDVB0BWhkLHI6rzYgOEP7eB8eWEsWvpqDQqeauOFzIjkC7VhXGiZVolkI5ehG3MvxHA0j@kMb4N5PAj86f3Yw@uxHwzGvj@LH9t@jjeB70@Cbh63M5w1@/5kysPwjjdr9UVEZ6QTcSzzFPZkp9P68QmoN4aTlV5W6n8HMIMtRSEqmyux0BpPRqBZ58Yy51UqVbrwXmqVXjmug03RvSxTCS@lyqiPLCY7eP4mo8VGErCIlquVw1uiRlZ0MlbuRVlZcSBKqwpmhg7ROkMlMmY4Zdg7/8V4rn8B)

There is a better Java solution already posted, but maybe my answer could interest some people.

I'm not sure how to properly explain it, but by trying to keep only 1 inline Java stream, my goal was to carry 3 numbers < 256 inside only 1 integer ("a", the accumulator of the stream reduction) using this structure:
`[_____max_value_____] [difference_between_max_and_min] [____min_value____]`
`<- 65 536 and over -> <-     from 256 to 65 535     -> <- from 0 to 255 ->`

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), <s>66</s> 57 bytes + <s>89</s> 86 = score <s>155</s> 143

```lua
s=...print(math.max(s:byte(1,#s))-math.min(s:byte(1,#s)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/2FZPT6@gKDOvRCM3sSRDLzexQqPYKqmyJFXDUEe5WFNTFyKcmYcqrPn//38lj9ScnHwdhfD8opwURSUA)

Program which takes command line argument for the strings.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 2 bytes + 57 = 59 score

```
:s
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%3As&i=Hello%0Aaaaaa%0ACode+Golf%0AStack+Exchange%0AASCII&m=2)

Apparently there's a builtin...

Answer (score 1):

## [KamilaLisp v0.2](https://github.com/kspalaiologos/kamilalisp), 88 + 35 = 123

```
[- $(foldl1 max) $(foldl1 min)]@ucs
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 95 bytes + 93 = 188

```go
func(s string)int{m:=rune(s[0]);n:=m;for _,r:=range s{if m<r{m=r};if n>r{n=r}};return int(m-n)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=tU9BasMwELzrFVudJHBCj8WuCiWENrdCDj2EkAjHck2tVVjJpSD8kl5MoY_KtS-pXPsL2csMu8zOzNd37YYLP-vyXdcVWN0ga-zZUVhyYwNn7EMTGFA_XTCLu8vBdFgKDz5Qg7VsMESbK-qwEn53u5cF5soWxhEcMkoHjemrj40Be0_RKuqLxPGBIibeF1SFjhDSH2EXKPvZ5ne0-U8jJETmfa52-8kz8ueqbV0Gr47a0w3PuB4n4cqdKnhyrUl8G1IjWH-Wb2OCtHjcrjYbnh2vnP_Ys0nsIVcwy32q8JL8QovCCC8l69ncdBgm_AM)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 39 bytes + 80 range = 119

```python
print(ord(max(a:=input()))-ord(min(a)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69EI78oRSM3sUIj0co2M6@gtERDU1NTFyyYmaeRCOQQrRAA)

A full program is one point better here because it avoids the minimum character " " (32) for "(" (40).

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 31 bytes + 33 = <sup><s>106 94</s></sup> 64

```arturo
function[x][do[x|min]x|max|sub]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?i2C66J)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 58 bytes + 93 = 151

```powershell
$args|%{$a=($_|% t*y)|%{[byte][char]$_}|sort;$a[-1]-$a[0]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL24RrVaJdFWQyW@RlWhRKtSE8iPTqosSY2NTs5ILIpVia@tKc4vKrFWSYzWNYzVBVIGsbX///9X8gCaka@jEJ5flJOiqKSglAgCQNo5PyVVwT0/Jw3IDi5JTM5WcK0AGpWXngoUcAx29vRUAgA)

Comment: Your score is your bytes plus the range of your code which in this case is 93 for a total of 151.

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku (Perl 6) (rakudo)](https://raku.org), 16 bytes + 78 = 94

```perl
+*.ords.minmax-1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kKDG7dMGy3EoFtTTbpaUlaboWG7S19PKLUor1cjPzchMrdA0hwjd1rLmKEysV0jSUPFJzcvKVNGF8dXQN6prWED0LFkBoAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 6 bytes + 66 = 72

```
eo:h-l
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FstS860ydHOWFCclF0OFFtx0VfJIzcnJ11EIzy_KSVFU4lJKBAEg7Zyfkqrgnp-TBmQHlyQmZyu4ViRnJOalpwIFHIOdPT2BNMRIJYhpAA)

```
eo:h-l
e       Convert to codepoints
 o      Sort
  :     Duplicate
   h    Head
    -   Subtract
     l  Last
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 2.4.1](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `K`, 4 bytes + 26 range = Score 30

```
G?-G
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=K&code=G%3F-G&inputs=This%20works%20apparently&header=&footer=)

If I knew what I was doing in 2021, this could have been 3 bytes with the `G` flag, but I never did figure out how to make the `K` flag play nice with other flags.

### Explained

```
G?-G­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
G     # ‎⁡Greatest character in the input
 ?-   # ‎⁢With each character code subtract from it
   G  # ‎⁣Greatest of those
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).